# Create a 'max downvote limit' for questions/answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, downvotes

What does the community think about a maximum number of downvotes a question or answer can receive? So for instance, once a question receives a total vote count of -10, that's enough, it's been maxed out.

The reason I suggest this is, if my question receives 1-2 downvotes, it was probably one guy who doesn't agree with me. If I receive 5 downvotes, I'm clearly wrong or need to greatly edit my question. If I receive 10, 20, 50, ok I get it, I'm wrong or I need to edit.

What benefit does it bring the creator of the question/answer to keep downvoting them?

Whether the vote count on an answer is -5 or -50, it'll be at the bottom of the answers, and the OP will understand they are wrong and need to fix it.

Comment: What problem does having a limit solve exactly?

Comment: No, if a user with plenty of reputation to lose posts a question that deserves 20 downvotes, I want to see that reflected in how much we trust that user: their reputation.

Comment: It seems like over 5 downvotes is just hitting somebody while they're on the ground. "You know you're wrong, but I want you to know you're really really wrong."

Comment: Also, your question is rather unclear. Are you talking about 10 downvotes or -10 score? The former would make no sense, the latter seems unneccessary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that is a really good point, hadn't thought about that

Comment: @l4mpi, apologies, -10 (or some threshold) overall score

Comment: @jb. If they *know* that their answer is wrong they'll generally *delete* the answer long before it collects that many downvotes.  The answers with -20 votes out there are answers in which the author really does think its right, and to which the community strongly disagrees.

Comment: You're taking downvoting personally.  The votes are on the **content**, not the person.  Users taking it personally is a widespread problem, and more education needs to be done to resolve *that*, not limit the effects to make someone feel better.

Comment: @Servy it is worth noting that answerer can't delete their post in case if it's accepted (IIRC this was exactly the case with a "most-downvoted" answer at -67)

Comment: @gnat True, although a mod flag can resolve that in most cases if the answer really *is* harmful and even the author believes it, a mod should at least consider deletion.  If all else fails, you can request disassociation.

Comment: @Servy: There are people that think it is fun to see how far the question will sink. See [Is it fair to active users? Can you kindly tell me and let me delete it by myself when I just posted a unconfortable question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172870) for an extreme example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure, and I have no pity at all for such users.

Comment: [A related proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286139/262399).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, if a user with plenty of reputation to lose posts a question that deserves 20 downvotes, I want to see that reflected in how much we trust that user: their reputation.

The downvotes do more than just take the post off the front page, or give a signal. They also affect reputation, by which we measure how trustworthy someone is. Being stupid enough to attract *that* many downvotes means we cannot trust you either.

Comment: Sadly it *won't* be reflected in their reputation, as a whopping 4 upvotes would completely offset 20 downvotes. Downvotes really aren't a deterrent to anybody with any substantial amount of reputation.

Comment: @meagar: It'll take 8 upvotes on a question to offset the rep loss.

Comment: Ah, on a question, sorry, yeah, so +5 per upvote. True.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Martijn's take on the relationship between a very bad post and the poster's reputation, but there's another important point that he missed:

**Downvotes and upvotes are really about the aggregate resulting score.** When you see a post, its score reflects its evaluation by any number of experts. This is a "wisdom of the (expert) crowds" feature. Limiting the number of downvotes a post can recieve limits the number of judgements that can be recorded; in the long term, that could skew the apparent worth of the post.